# How to concatenate a list with conditional entries to one string with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a csv file which includes a field, where different elements should be listed, based on a condition for each entry.

In example I have this table

```
id    col1    col2    col3
1     false   false   true
2     true    true    true
3     true    false   true
```

The csv should look like this:

```
id,params
"1","col3"
"2","col1,col2,col3"
"3","col1,col3"
```

I thought of something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    CONCAT(
        IF(`col1`, 'col1,',''), 
        IF(`col2`, 'col2,',''), 
        IF(`col3`, 'col3','')
    ) AS `params`
FROM `table`
```

but the problem is, that this will only work if the last column (`col3`) is true, otherwise it will have a trailing comma at the end.

Is this possible in the MySQL SQL dialect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `null` instead of an empty string in the `IF` conditions and use `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate the values.

```
SELECT id, concat_ws(',',c1,c2,c3) params
FROM (SELECT 
      id,
      IF(`col1`, 'col1',null) c1, 
      IF(`col2`, 'col2',null) c2, 
      IF(`col3`, 'col3',null) c3
      FROM t) x
```

Or

```
SELECT id,
concat_ws(',',if(col1,'col1',null),if(col2,'col2',null),if(col3,'col3',null)) params
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add more `if` statements with your current approach:

```
select id, 
  concat(if(col1, 'col1', ''),
         if(col2, concat(if(col1,',',''), 'col2'), ''),
         if(col3, concat(if(col1 or col2,',',''), 'col3'), '')) as newcol
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e0c9/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is basically how I did it before and it's feasible when you have three columns, but not if you go beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to just use MySQL's two argument SUBSTRING function, along with a slight modification to your original concatenation:

```
SUBSTRING(
CONCAT(
        IF(`col1`, ',col1',''), 
        IF(`col2`, ',col2',''), 
        IF(`col3`, ',col3','')
    ) AS `params`
, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove any leading and trailing comma ',' from output.

`For More Info:` [MySQL TRIM() Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

```
select id,trim(both ',' from CONCAT(
        IF(`col1`, 'col1,',''), 
        IF(`col2`, 'col2,',''), 
        IF(`col3`, 'col3','')
    )) as params from q;
```

**FYI: another alternate** Select query using case and trim.

```
select id, 
TRIM(BOTH ',' from concat(case  when col1 is not null and col1 = true then 'col1' else '' end ,
case    when col2 is not null and col2 = true then ',col2' else '' end ,
case    when col3 is not null and col3 = true then ',col3' else '' end)) as params
 from q;
```

Comment: I like the trim solution.